# How can I size columns in a gridlayout?

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I'm building a GridLayout.
I have 8 columns.
I want the first TextView to span 6 cols and display the text on 2 lines.
I want the next TextView to span 1 col and to display a Number from 1 to 10.
Finally the next TextView display the following text "/10"

So far I've achieved what I want, but not so much with the alignments.

Code:

```
<GridLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:columnCount="7" 
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:rowCount="8">
    <TextView
        android:minLines="2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="5"
        android:layout_columnWeight="4"

        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/qol1"
        android:text="Avoir du temps pour moi" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/score_qol1"
        android:text="6"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"
        android:gravity="right" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/score_qol1_10"
        android:text="/10"
        android:gravity="right" />
</GridLayout>
```

The result is the following:

[image]

As you can Imagine, I'd like the last cell to wrap its content, the middle one to be aligned on the left and the first cell to take all the space available, according to the mockup I have:

[image]

I know that the last 2 cells will always take approximately the same space. I don't wan't to use fixed sizes because of the diversity of screen resolutions.

I thought that layout_columnWeight would be the solution, but it does not work.

Comment: have you tried looking into constraint layout, it is advanced has more features https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/index.html

Comment: I was unsure it would be available with Xamarin.Android, but it is. Will do.

Comment: I guess you choose a `GridLayout` thinking it would be easier to build the layout. But your layout is so simple that it becomes hard. You could achieve this by using `ConstraintLayout` or `LinearLayout`setting `weight` attibute in each view.

Comment: @Giovanne I ended up using a LinearLayout inside a row of the GridLayout and this is working fine.